# cross platform mobile app framework suggestion

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, mobile, cross-platform, mobile-application

I am trying to build an app for iPhone, Android and Blackberry (basically for all smart phones). I have worked with jQuery Mobile previously, and I was not entirely happy with the result. So I want to try something else, and I was wondering what would be the best replacement for jQuery Mobile. I have heard a lot about Sencha Touch and wink Toolkit, but I don't know what framework to pick that works on as many smart phones as possible. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked which platrofms the alternatives support?

Comment: Yes, they both support Blackberry, but I'm not sure if Sencha Touch supports Blackberry devices without touch functionality. Besides that I'm not sure if these 2 alternatives are the best choices.

Answer (score 1):

I use Flash Builder 4.5 with the latest Flex 4.5.1 and it is great to develop for iOS Android and Blackberry also in one time. Phonegap is great if you want to use the full power of HTML5 and CSS3.

Btw with the Flash Builder and the certificate... you can actually use a fake certificate downloaded from internet. There is one I know about which you can use just by "customizing" it a bit and then you can easily build your app for iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad with not paying anything.

Answer (score 0):

[Flash Builder 4.5](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adobe-technology-sneaks-2011/sneak-peek-of-mobile-application-development-with-flex-and-flash-builder/)

Comment: I tried to work with Flash builder but it requires me to have a certificate, witch I dont have, is it possible to work with flash builder without the certificate??

Comment: In order to submit an app to the market-place (both android and iOS) you must have a certificate...

Comment: You can install the app on a jailbroken device without a certificate, you need it just for publishing

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com). It only supports iOS, Android, and Black Berry, but it looks and feels native.  It allows you to access the camera and do other neat things.  Your can also access native code you wrote (Objective-C on iOS, Java on Android, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If what interests you is the widest possible support, then phonegap + jquery mobile are probably your best option.

On the downside, jquery mobile is less performant and looks less native than sencha. On the bright side, development is much easier with jqm.

Answer (score 0):

We switched recently from JQuery Mobile to JQ.Mobi/Intel App Framework (http://www.jqmobi.com/).

We had a lot of problem with JQuery Mobile, slow, transition, fixed toolbar, and other bugs.

JQ.Mobi and JQ.UI use the same logic as JQuery Mobile (HTML markup), but it's very fast because they don't try to support every device on the planet (only webkit browser: iOS, Android, Blackberry...). Combined with Backbone, we now have a solid architecture !

Answer (score 0):

Try Kendo UI

http://www.kendoui.com

or Enyo:

http://enyojs.com/showcase/

Both seem quite good.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody reading this old thread looking for something that's not obsolete, checkout [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/): "Google’s portable UI toolkit for building beautiful, natively-compiled applications for mobile, web, and desktop from a single codebase."

Answer (score -1):

Give phoneGap a look:

http://www.phonegap.com/

Comment: I have already worked with phoneGap. PhoneGap makes it possible to deploy the web-app as a native app to different app stores. So it can be used along with a framework, but PhoneGap alone is not a framework in the sense that it has its library and UI widgets.